# NestJS crashing on throwing http exception

Tags: nestjs

```
main.controller.ts:135
throw new NotFoundException('Swap not found');
^
NotFoundException: Swap not found
```

I have a pretty simple request in a controller

```
@Get("/details")
@ApiResponse({
    status: 200,
    description: 'Returns the details',
})
async getDetails(
    @Query('id') id: string
): Promise<Result> {
    let details = await this.databaseService.find(id)
    if (!details) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Swap not found');
    }
    return {
        details: details,
    }
}
```

After the exception is thrown, NestJS also stops from running!?
How do I avoid this? I know about the exception filters, but that's for custom exceptions, right? I use a default one.

Still, just in case, I've added a global one to test and same behaviour: `app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());`

Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: that's weird. The default behavior is catching that exception and replying with 500 error.  Can you provide some [minimum repo](https://minimum-reproduction.wtf) that reproduces this?

Comment: I do get the json before crashing ( statusCode: 404 ). Any requests afterward are not reaching the server ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: that snippet looks fine. You shouldn't get any crash with that pattern. I'll help you if you share some full code. You can start building it with this one: https://gitlab.com/micalevisk/minimum-reproduction--nestjs-v8

Comment: oh, that's great, will definitely save me some time! Thanks! I'll get back to you with a fork

Comment: Strange, it worked with my code in that repo.

Comment: I'll try to see where is the issue coming from! Thanks for support@

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue, I fixed it by awaiting for the task to be done before throwing, I threw an error after sending the response, so I just added an await in my service where it is required.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the function inside your service file,and await the responses properly before returning it.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you return your expection throw from the controller otherwise the api gives you the connection error

```
@Get("/details")
@ApiResponse({
    status: 200,
    description: 'Returns the details',
})
async getDetails(
    @Query('id') id: string
): Promise<Result> {
    let details = await this.databaseService.find(id)
    if (!details) {
        // Add the return here!
        return throw new NotFoundException('Swap not found');
    }
    return {
        details: details,
    }
}
```